# Executar arquivo Appimage em background no ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Efetuei o download da aplicação [`cerebro`](https://github.com/KELiON/cerebro) para o ubuntu 16.04 porém para executa-lo eu sempre preciso abrir o terminal e escrever:

```
`./cerebro-0.2.6-x86_64.AppImage`
```

E então o software é aberto porém o terminal fica "travado" (sim eu sei que posso abrir outro com `CTRL + ALT + T` e outra aba com `CTRL + SHIFT + T`).

Tentei adicionar a tarefa para executar quando o `S.O` for carregado em `gnone-session-preferences` mas a aplicação precisa de permissão `sudo` para ser executada, logo isso gera um erro.

Como posso fazer para esse arquivo `.AppImage` seja executado em background e inicie toda vez que o `S.O` for iniciado também?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `upstart` que é usado pra iniciar aplicativos no boot ou em determinados momentos do sistema:

```
# Start

description "Start App"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems)
script
<caminho>/cerebro-0.2.6-x86_64.AppImage
end script
```

Este modelo deve te atender, você deve criar um arquivo com a extenção `.conf` e colocar ele na pasta `/etc/init`.

Consulte a documentação pra saber mais : http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

**Nota**: Em algumas versões do `ubuntu`, o `upstart` se encontrava inabilitado, para habilitar, basta seguir este tutorial: https://www.maketecheasier.com/re-enable-upstart-ubuntu/